# Rails post controller not passing user association to React view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, model-view-controller

I'm trying to make a basic CRUD store app with Rails and React, but I'm stuck on displaying the author (user) association of the post. The post itself shows just fine. I'm trying to avoid using jbuilder so I can understand the problem I'm having.

The current show method in the controller, which works:

```
controllers/post_controller.rb

  def show
    if post
      render json: post
    else
      render json: post.errors
    end
  end
```

The current React view, which works:

```
app/javascript/components/Post.js

import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

class Post extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { post: { description : '' } };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const {
      match: {
        params: { id }
      }
    } = this.props;

    const url = `/api/v1/show/${id}`;

    fetch(url)
      .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response.json();
        }
        throw new Error("Network response was not ok.");
      })
      .then(response => this.setState({ post: response }))
      .catch(() => this.props.history.push("/posts"));
  }

  render() {
    const { post } = this.state;
    let descriptionList = "No descriptions present";

    if (post.description.length > 0) {
      descriptionList = post.description
        .split(",")
        .map((description, index) => (
          <li key={index} className="list-group-item">
            {description}
          </li>
        ));
    }

    return (
      <div className="">
        <div className="hero position-relative d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
          <img
            src={post.image}
            alt={`${post.description} image`}
            className="img-fluid position-absolute"
          />
          <div className="overlay bg-dark position-absolute" />
        </div>
        <div className="container py-5">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-sm-12 col-lg-3">
              <ul className="list-group">
                <h5 className="mb-2">Description</h5>
                {descriptionList}
                <div>{post.title}</div>
                 <div>${(post.price * .01).toLocaleString()}</div>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <Link to="/posts" className="btn btn-link">
            Back to all posts
          </Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

}

export default Post;
```

When I add `render json: post, include: :user` to the controller and `{post.user.email}` and  `render() { const { post, user } = this.state;`
to the view, the error message in the console is `cannot read property 'email' of undefined`. When I try to define the user in the controller method `user = post.user.email` and in the view `{user}`, the terminal error is:

`NoMethodError (undefined method 'oswaldo@daugherty.info' for #<Post id: 5, title: "Post 5", description: "You can't synthesize the bandwidth without compres...", image: "https://loremflickr.com/300/300/cats 5", price: 883105, rating: nil, review: nil, created_at: "2021-01-31 23:26:03", updated_at: "2021-01-31 23:26:03", user_id: 5>):`

I've checked my database and all the associations display correct there. In short, I don't know how to send the post's user association correctly to the view. What am I missing? Any help appreciated because I'm really spinning my wheels on this one.

Comment: Can you post your updated controller and component code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might be facing the bug [reported bug](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/576).

If you are only looking email from related user record, you can use following

```
# in Post model

  delegate :email, to: :user, prefix: true, allow_nil: true

# and while rendering

use Post.as_json(methods: [:user_email])
```

Comment: Thank you raviture! Looks like this is it.